# How to get Gatsby Images based on results of PageQuery?

Tags: graphql, gatsby

I'd like to do something like the following so I can get Gatsby Images dynamically:

```
const image = 'gastby-astronaut.png';

export const imageQuery = graphql`
  { allImageSharp (
    filter: {
      fluid: {
        originalName: {
          regex: "/${image}/"
        }
      }
    }
  ){
  edges { 
    node {
      fluid {
        originalName
      }
    }
  }
}
}
`;
```

However, I can't figure out how to connect this query to an initial query that would get the 'gatsby-astronaut.png', or perform this query from a subcomponent with a . I get this error when I try this:

```
Error: BabelPluginRemoveGraphQL: String interpolations are not allowed 
in graphql fragments. Included fragments should be referenced as
 `...MyModule_foo`.
```

Any suggestions on the proper way to return Gatsby Images dynamically?

Comment: Thanks for pinging me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah, yeah Gatsby extracts GraphQL queries from your pages through static analysis: they load the file as text, parse it, and extract the query, all before the actual file gets executed. This means that your typical tagged-template literal functionality isn't there.

The only way to filter is through context provided when `createPage` is called from `gatsby-node.js`. I.e. if you do this:

```
exports.createPages = ({ graphql, actions }) =>
  graphql(`some query here`).then(result => {
    actions.createPage({
      path: "/output-path/",
      component: path.resolve(`./src/templates/your_template.jsx`),
      context: { image: result.data.yourImage },
    })
  })
```

Then you can do this in your page query:

```
query SomePage($image: String!) {
  allImageSharp (
    filter: {
      fluid: {
        originalName: {
          regex: $image
        }
      }
    }
  ){
    edges { 
      node {
        fluid {
          originalName
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I wonder if this new Schema Customization coming to Gatsby will be able to solve this problem too: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/blog/2019-03-04-new-schema-customization/ ... the `createResolvers` is what I'm looking at...

Comment: @EricJohnson Without knowing more about what you're trying to do it's hard to say, but I don't think it'll help you here—`createResolvers` allows you to augment types and nodes, but doesn't alter the way Gatsby processes your GraphQL queries.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution I came up with... pretty janky, but it works:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import React from 'react';
import Img from 'gatsby-image';
import { useStaticQuery, graphql } from 'gatsby';


const Image = ({ imageYouWant }) => {
  const data = useStaticQuery(
    graphql`
      query allTheImagesQuery{
        allImageSharp {
          edges {
            node {
              fluid(maxWidth:1000) {
                ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
                originalName
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }`,
  );

  const TheImageYouWant = data.allImageSharp.edges
    .filter(edge => edge.node.fluid.originalName === imageYouWant)
    .map(myImage => <Img fluid={myImage.node.fluid} />);

  return (
    <>
      { TheImageYouWant }
    </>
  );
};


Image.propTypes = {
  imageYouWant: PropTypes.string,
};

Image.defaultProps = {
  imageYouWant: '',
};

export default Image;
```

Comment: Is the rest of your content not being queried w/ GraphQL? Normally you don't need to do this because your textual content and references to images can be defined alongside one another, and you can use `childImageSharp` inside of a path node to fetch the additional sharp image data.

Comment: I'll give this a shot... I was having some trouble with GraphQL syntax at first so maybe I missed something!

Comment: @coreyward is there a special way I need to define my image references in my JSON so that Gatsby recognizes them as images?

Comment: When Gatsby boots it infers node types from your data; if you have strings that look like paths, Gatsby will check the first one to see if a file exists at that location. If it does, it declares that node as a File. Subsequently, `gatsby-plugin-sharp` will add a `childImageSharp` node under these File nodes. So basically you just need to have valid path references in your content. Are you using a particular source plugin to define your data?

Comment: @coreyward yeah I'm using `gatsby-source-filesystem` and I have `gatsby-plugin-sharp` installed. I tried changing the path in my JSON to the full path both, `/src/images/gatsby-icon.png` and `/images/gatsby-icon.png` but it still seems to be inferring it as a string: https://www.screencast.com/t/Xw07RDpN5